# image slider full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using nivo slider for image slide to show on full-screen. I am using about 1400 by 900px image. Everything is doing good but when I zoom in or out the browser.
and i think the image will be not displayed in its proportions when viewed on different screen size

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sliders" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="webimg/slider1.jpg" />
        <img src="webimg/slider2.jpg" />
        <img src="webimg/slider3.jpg" />
        <img src="webimg/slider4.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.nivoSlider {
    position:fixed;
    top:-16px;
    left:0px;
}
.nivoSlider img {position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#sliders').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 
        slices: 35, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 3500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 11000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
        directionNavHide: false, // Only show on hover
        controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel: false, // Use image rel for thumbs
        keyboardNav: false, // Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover: false, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
```

What I want is that the images should remain full-screen every time.
 Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
please help me with this.
and also please tell me what size of image should i use is 1400*900 px is ok or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this changes in your **css** code to auto resize on different screen resolution or browser zoom in/out:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f1o0bh1b/2/)

```
.nivoSlider img {
  height:  100%;
  width:  100%; 
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

Comment: why max-width? Can't we specify a "width:100%" instead, and "heigh:100%".

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;`?

Comment: @lindsay i tested with that code and don't work, you can play in [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f1o0bh1b/2/). `height:  100%;width:  100%;` makes resize happens

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.nivoSlider {
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

If this is not working, then change position fixed to absolute and add an width and height of 100% to your actual .nivoSlider in CSS.